# How to style and position ::before element so it doesn't affect button size?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a  button that has a weekday and hour in the center,  and a small YYYY-MM-DD date in the top left corner. I'm using the :before pseudo-selector however, I would like that the button size and main text didn't get affected by the ::before element, right now it's making the button bigger and changing the main text's position. Also, I would like to position it in the top left corner. [codepen](https://codepen.io/jp_coelho/pen/ZEWVGRV)

```css
.hour-btn {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.15vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  padding: 2vw 2vw;
  margin: 1vw 1vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% / 3.5);
  height: 6vw;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 1.4vw;
}

.hour-btn[title]::before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 52;
  top: -2vw;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
}
```

```html
<button title="2020-10-24" class="hour-btn">Saturday 20:20
 </button>
```

Comment: use `px`  unit  instead of `vw` for all like width, padding and  margin etc

Comment: Do you want button text on left? Or title

Comment: You should read about the difference between vw, vh, em, rem, px... etc. Also you're misunderstanding how the :before pseudo-element works.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I fixed it :

```css
.hour-btn {
  border-style: solid;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-width: 0vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  padding: 2vw 2vw;
  margin: 1vw 1vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% / 3.5);
  height: 6vw;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: gray;
  border-color: blue;

}

.hour-btn[title]::before {
  content: attr(title);
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  top: 2px;
  left: 6px;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  font-weight: lighter;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<button title="2020-10-24" class="hour-btn">Saturday 20:20
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this css.

```css
.hour-btn {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.15px;
  border-radius: 0.5px;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  /*margin: 1vw 1vw;*/
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*width: calc(100% / 3.5);*/
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.hour-btn[title]::before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 52;
  top: 0.25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  left: 0.25px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button title="2020-10-24" class="hour-btn">Saturday 20:20
 </button>
```

Answer (score -1):

**What about this:-**

```css
.hour-btn {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.15vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  padding: 2vw 2vw;
  margin: 1vw 1vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% / 3.5);
  height: 6vw;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 1.4vw;
}

.hour-btn[title]::before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 52;
  top: -1.5vw;
  left: -5vw;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
}
```

```html
<button title="2020-10-24" class="hour-btn">Saturday 20:20
 </button>
```